# schedule python job based on files exist in a folder

Tags: python

Need some help in scheduling a python. I would like to run the script @ interval of 2 minutes based on files exist in a folder.

If file exist, it will run the scheduler based on 2 min interval, if there are no files exist, it won't run the scheduler at all.

Check_file_exist(), function return True for file found otherwise False return.

```py
import schedule

import time

//function to be called by scheduler

   def job():
   
//return True for file found else False

   def check_for_files:
   

def main()

     while True:
        if not check_for_files():
          print("no file to process")
        else:
          schedule.every(2).minutes.do(job)

        while True:
         schedule.run_pending()
         time.sleep(1)

if  __name__ ==  "__main__":

    main()
```

If there is no data in input folder , scheduler never run , even if user place the files after first cycle or second cycle i.e after 4 min interval or 6 min inteval. Please suggest.

Comment: Try this https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists

Comment: my concern is to run scheduler based on file exist in folder only and at interval of 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
def main()

     while True:
        if not check_for_files():
          print("no file to process")
        else:
          schedule.every(2).minutes.do(job)

        while True: # never jump out
         schedule.run_pending()
         time.sleep(1)
```

you never jump out the second while True. so you just check the path only once.